# Mootools loop morph/tween

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am new to mootools and would like to know how I could make a morph or a tween loop forever because I want to chain colors together. I asked because I don't know if there is a better way than just use a while(1).

Answer (score 1):

setup your chain of effects as a function that self-calls after the last onComplete on the fx instance.